# Resuming a thread by using notifyAll

Tags: java

Take the [Pausing a Thread](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/PauseThread.html) example. If I use `notifyAll` instead of notify, is there any side effect, and is it necessary?

Comment: I know I am digressing, but its better to use concurrency utilities to wait and notify.

Comment: @doc_180, then show me a common known way to pause and resume thread using concurrency utilities.

Comment: You will do worse than reading Doug Lea's book on concurrency. Anyways here goes a simple executor and latch sample. Code sample in seperate answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that example, it will not make any difference, because there's only 1 thread waiting.

The difference between `notify` and `notifyAll` is that the latter wakes all waiters, instead of just one.

Comment: The other thing to note is that with notify() you have no control over what thread is woken, it's an arbitrary one that's picked. So if you need to bias priority at all, you'll need to look for a more advanced implementation in java.util.concurrent.

Answer (score 1):

In “*Effective Java”* item 69, Bloch suggests “**always use notifyAll**”.

Answer (score 0):

Using notifyAll as opposed to notify is important if you can have multiple parties waiting on the object. If only one thread ever waits, then there is no difference between calling notify vs notifyAll.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new runnable. In the run method "start" countdownlatch is waiting and will not allow execution unless it is released using calling countdown on that latch for a predefined time. In this case 1. (since start is passed 1 as concurrent no)

// Revised Answer. 
// A runnable class.

```
public  class WorkerThread implements Runnable
    {
        CountDownLatch start;

        CountDownLatch end;

        String name;

        WorkerThread(CountDownLatch startLatch, CountDownLatch stopLatch)
        {
            this.start = startLatch;
            this.end = stopLatch;

        }

        public void run()
        {
            try
            {

                start.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Will run when start is released ");
            end.countDown();
        }
    }
```

// This is the entry point method that executes the worker thread.

```
public  void  initiateProcess (final int count) {
           CountDownLatch start = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch stop = new CountDownLatch(count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            new Thread(new WorkerThread(start, stop))
                    .start();
        }
        System.out.println("Go");
// This is where start latch is released. Now worked thread can complete its function.
        start.countDown();
        try
        {


 // Stop will wait until stop latch is countdowned to zero from count param. (see count param)
            stop.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
```

Comment: It does not show exactly how you suspend and resume a thread.

Comment: Hmm... You are probably correct, I was in a hurry to post some small latch sample. I have revised answer.

Comment: Please copy this class and run in a debugger mode. It will help in understanding countdownlatch better.